# How do I get the difference in minutes from 2 timestamp columns?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Can't seem to figure this out. Just need the difference in minutes between 2 oracle timestamp columns.

```
END_TS                                  START_TS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-NOV-13 01.52.14.000000 PM                            11-NOV-13 01.51.14.000000 PM
11-NOV-13 02.20.47.000000 PM                            11-NOV-13 02.19.47.000000 PM
18-NOV-13 12.44.54.000000 PM                            18-NOV-13 12.34.02.000000 PM
22-NOV-13 12.02.09.000000 AM                            22-NOV-13 12.02.08.000000 AM
```

Answer (score 14):

```
select
  round(
    (cast(current_timestamp as date) - cast(<other_timestamp> as date))
    * 24 * 60
  ) as diff_minutes
from <some_table>;
```

This is what I used to calculate the difference between the current timestamp and a heart beat table entry for latency monitoring.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your table is called `TS`:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT (DAY FROM (end_ts-start_ts))*24*60*60+
EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (end_ts-start_ts))*60*60+
EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (end_ts-start_ts))*60+
EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (end_ts-start_ts)))/60
FROM TS;
```

Common sense, to be honest.

Reduce everything to Seconds

- A Minute is 60 Seconds
- An Hour is 60 Minutes (or 60 * 60 seconds)
- A Day is 24 Hours or (24 * 60 * 60)

We perform the difference for each of the elements, EXTRACT all of the values, convert them to the base (Second) and then scale them back up to the desired level of granularity (Minutes).

(May need an `EXTRACT(YEAR` too).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a better option

```
select (cast(your_column1 as date) - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60 
     - (cast(your_column2 as date) - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60 
from your_table;
```

Comment: This should be `24 * 60`, as `24 * 60 * 60` will give seconds instead of minutes.

Answer (score -3):

This is from postgresql, but I would hope oracle is as advanced as postgresql ...

```
Select extract(epoch from stop_time-start_time)) ; #(in seconds)
Select extract(epoch from stop_time-start_time))/60 ; #(in minutes)
```

Comment: No, `epoch` is [not supported](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639) in Oracle's EXTRACT.